# How to add a popover link on tumblr

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, popover

I'm a new user to Tumblr and I see other people with links to their blogs commented on their posts. I know how to use HTML to add and edit the link, but how do I include the popover feature that appears when you hover over a blog link? 

Is there a built in way to do it via the post editor, do I need to edit my template, or is there something else I'm missing?

I have tried googling it and inspecting the page, but have had no luck. Could someone please point me in the right direction or show me the code for how to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Tumblr should add it automatically. It does if you tag a blog, for example `@user`. It sometimes adds it to general links to blogs as well. It's not controllable by the user as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all I need to do is just add a link that's an actual blog.